# overridePendingTransition behaiving different with intent flags

Tags: android, android-intent, android-animation

I am using a slide in animation to open activities in my app by using overridePendingTransition. Earlier when i used it after startActivity(intent) withiout intent flags , it was working fine. With intent flags it was not working so i used overridePendingTransition in onResume() method now when the activity is started for the first time the animation is fine but when the same instance is brought to front because of intent flag the animation is working but its not smooth . The second time the activity start from right to slide in(which is correct) but it appears with jerk.

These are the intent flags i am using

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

What should be done to solve this.Help Plz

This is the code i use for slide in animation i.e enter_anim

```
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

since i dont wanna give any exit_anim

```
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

Comment: For test increase the duration of slide in and slide out and test it and post the behavior..

Comment: i did it , still appears with a jerk

Comment: post ur animation code

Comment: have posted the animation xml files

Comment: @Ravi : Did you find the solution to your problem? Even I am facing the same problem. There is a jerk. I have also posted my problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176141/is-transition-animation-not-possible-when-using-flag-activity-clear-top . Can you tell which device you tested on and it's OS version

Comment: Unfortunately due to time boundation i had to give up the animation.

Comment: @Ravi : ohhh:( Which device did you test your code and OS version?

Answer (score 2):

try the following code

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left_first,
                        R.anim.slide_out_left_first);
slide_in_left_first:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" />

slide_out_left_first:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="200"

    android:fromXDelta="0%"

    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

Comment: still there is a jerk . its not smooth like when its first created

Comment: Its wrking fine at my end have you check device setting animation

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left_first,
    R.anim.slide_out_left_first);

Comment: Try two activities A and B A is the starting one then call B and then from b call A again . when i call A again that time is the problem

Answer (score 1):

So try below code in your manifest:- in application add this

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```